# BlackBerry SQLite multiple connections problem

Tags: database, sqlite, blackberry, connection

I have a question regarding SQLite on BlackBerry OS 5.0 and up. Our application has two entry points, one background process that starts when the device boots and one GUI process that starts when the user clicks the application icon. Both of these processes require database access to the same database. For some reason, I can't seem to have two open connections to the database, I get a DatabaseIOException when I try to open the second connection (I also get a message that says "File System error 12"). Also, one of the SQLite statements hangs on the 'prepare' method, perhaps this is related to the two open connections, I don't know.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be due to open Database that is already opened.Try to use only one Database.open() method.

Comment: Thanks for all of your replies! However, I haven't been able to fix it yet. i've tried putting the database helper in the runtime store and I've also tried read-only connections, but the system still seems to hang on the prepare method of one of the sqlitestatements. The debugger shows the following stack after a call to prepare():

 

pendingOperation.wait();

prepareAsync();

prepare();

[...]



It seems like there's deadlock or something, but I don't know what could be causing it. I'm sure that only one of the processes is accessing the database at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Use [RuntimeStore](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/RuntimeStore.html) to share the same database connection object between the foreground and background apps.

Comment: I've tried this method, but I didn't get it to work, see my comment on the above answer from Himanshu Dudhat